# How to get API data and pass to a chart directive?

Tags: angular

Based off of stackoverflow and github issue posts, I've been able to grab API data, and also display a chart. Now I'm having a tough time passing that data to the chart correctly.

To the best of my ability, I tried to replicate my program:  [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DbOGKUxTOlwcWpOhdW59?p=preview).

On my local server, I'm able to pass the following data to my chart directive: (I also commented in my `app/volume-charts.ts` where I console.logged `this.data`)

[image: Chart Data Object]

Printing out the Chart itself once data is supposedly passed to it:
`console.log(this.barChart)`  (Also mentioned in `app/volume-charts.ts` in plunkr)

[image]

Things I did in my code that might seem questionable: in `app.component.ts`, I add references to a chart (line 70), and remove them (line 43). The chart had a [problem](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/187) with removing old data. It looked like I just had to remove the old canvas and add another for my next chart.

Any helpful nudges in the right direction is appreciated. It looks like the data is reaching the chart directive file, but when I apply the data to the chart, it doesn't work.

Edit: I'm using Chart.js for creating the chart. Also, when inputting a string into the `input` field, you need to use existing symbols (i.e. GOOG or AAPL) because I don't have any validations or error catches on incorrect symbols.

Edit2: Ok, I think I fixed the api call. I forgot to import rxjs. Plunkr updated.

Comment: Looks like this is because Chartjs has problem with canvases when they are hidden initially. I had this problem couple of time, and once in ng2 app. I solved it by switching to highcharts. I suggest you to do the same: not only it will just work better but also, chartjs is very hard to customize, chances that this you will have other problems.

Comment: @dfsq Ok, so I figured out how to make the charts appear. I was messing around with it a bit on a separate plunker and got rid of the api call (which shouldn't be a problem I think?) Here is the other [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kf6DEn7jrmKMb9aFb5GI?p=preview). I changed angular2, http, rxjs, polyfills to beta.0

Comment: *"I figured out how to make the charts appear."* Doesn't render any chart for me anyway.

Comment: @dfsq oops forgot to save it lol, sorry should be updated. I'll still most likely switch to highcharts as I dont want to revert to an older beta version x.x